# how to use ajax request in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, xss, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create my first fiddle. So here's what I want to do with jquery

```
$('.list').live('click', function(){
    var dataPass = 'uid='+ uid;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: dataPass,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            //Do something
        }
    });
});
```

So how/where do I write the codes for `test.php` file? It's going to return some html markup.

Answer (score 11):

It's not possible to make an AJAX request to a domain other than the current one, as it's a pretty basic security risk.

jsFiddle have an [API](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) for testing AJAX requests which you should use instead.

Comment: Possibly the same, updated url: https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests

Answer (score 6):

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thewiseguy99/YUWB2/) of what you are probably looking for.

I used http://echo.jsontest.com but you can substitute for your valid URL.

```
var echo = function(dataPass) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: dataPass,
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){
            alert("UID=" + json.uid + "\nName=" + json.value);
        }
    });
};

$('.list').live('click', function(){
    $.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/uid/12345/value/nuno_bettencourt", function(data) {
        var json = {
            json: JSON.stringify(data),
            delay: 1
        };
        echo(json);;
    });​ 
});
```

Comment: How does this work?  Shouldn't the $.get() call be disallowed by same origin policy?  /confused

Comment: The remote server adds this HTTP header to tell the browser it allows the cross domain request `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`. See the headers in Network tab of your browser's debug tool.

Comment: @rych, this is set on the server. Here is a node.js example, `response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
`response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");`
`response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");`