# jsfiddle and json request

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jsfiddle

OK, I would like to do my first jsfiddle… and another learning curve… 
I have a code (google maps v3) that has an ajax request.

The request is part of the code and is used to push markers on google maps canvas. 
My question is how to have a basic json data, like this {"id":"1","0":"1",lat":"40.626953","9":"40.626953","lng":"-73.900055","10":"-73.900055"} inside the jsfiddle?
I cut the file down to what I really need, lat and lng. All other fields are not important for this purpose. 
I saw [this](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374271/how-to-use-ajax-request-in-jsfiddle/), but still can't figure it out. I don't want to have the file in the "result" of the css+html+js. I just need to use it to plot my map, which will be second fiddle.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data passed via the json-parameter must be encoded, e.g.

```
data: {"json":JSON.stringify({"lat":"40.626953","lng":"-73.900055"})}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tJNuV/

Note: for browsers without JSON-support you must include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)