# event.preventDefault() is not working when clicking a link

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with event.preventDefault().

So what I am doing is sending an getJSON request to generate the body of a table. so it will return something like this
`<tr><td>......</td><td>2</td></tr>`................ etc

then I have a table body like so

```
<table>
<tbody id="activities_list">
</tbody>
</table>
```

The I set the activities_list to the value that was returned from the ajax request.
everything is working fine except the event.preventDefault() it does not prevent the click. So when a user click on a link he/she is still being directed to the url.

Why isn't it preventing defaults? note that the link have a class "HistoricActivities" and they are also generated by ajax request.

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $('.sub_note').shorten({
            moreText: 'read more',
            lessText: 'read less',
            showChars: '100'
        }); 

        $('.HistoricActivities.dummy_his').on('click', function(event){
            //reset
            event.preventDefault();

            $('#activities_list').html('');
            var pg = getURLParameter('page', null);

            $.getJSON("ajax/loader-display-previos-calls.php", {
                    account_id: <?php echo $account_id; ?>,
                    page: pg
                },function (data) {

                    if ( ! data) 
                    return; 

                    if(data.error === false){       
                        $('#activities_list').html(data.msg); 
                    }


                }
            );
        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show the HTML that goes along with this.

Comment: Does your handler work at all? Most likely you need an event delegation to attach the event since you said they are generated dynamically.

Comment: `$("#activities_list").on("click", ".HistoricActivities.dummy_his", function() { somestuff(); });`

Comment: Try to return false at the end of your click event function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the  element is dynamically generated, you must use:

```
$("#activities_list").on("click", ".HistoricActivities.dummy_his", function(e) { 

    somestuff(); 
    e.preventDefault();

  }
);
```

Comment: This did the prevention. However, the code getURLParameter('page', null) is not returning the page number. it is always returning the last one. the linke are something like this <a class-"HistoricActivities" href="filename.php?page=4">4</a>  so I need to know what page number the user clicked on. this is what I did       if(data.error === false){  
       $('#activities_list').html(data.msg).on('click', '.HistoricActivities', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(getURLParameter('page', null));
       });

Comment: I don't know how to create a fiddle code with an ajax request on a second page. My code is stored on a local server and it is not public.

Comment: check this question so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374271/how-to-use-ajax-request-in-jsfiddle

Comment: I am still unable to create a live code :(  I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/t5rv9/5/

Comment: I solved it. I posted an answer below but I gave you the correct answer since your answer gave me what I need to solve it.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the elements must exist for the event binding to work. (That is, you're attempting to add click listeners on the page load, not when you're adding the html.)

It looks like you're building the html

```
$('#activities_list').html(data.msg);
```

but aren't attaching any click event listeners to the html elements. Maybe something along the lines of

```
$('#activities_list')
    .html(data.msg)
    .find('a.HistoricActivities').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: This did the prevention. However, the code getURLParameter('page', null) is not returning the page number. it is always returning the last one. the linke are something like this <a class-"HistoricActivities" href="filename.php?page=4">4</a>  so I need to know what page number the user clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

If the link is generated, be sure that, when you bind the "click" event, it already exists in the dom and

```
$('.HistoricActivities.dummy_his')
```

actually selects it. A couple of old fashioned

```
alert('someone clicked me');
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.... here is what I have done.

created a recursive function that does the ajax request.

then I called it when link is clicked.

```
<script>

function recall(page){
    $.getJSON("ajax/loader-display-previos-calls.php", {
        account_id: <?php echo $account_id; ?>,
        page: page
    },function (data) {

        if ( ! data) 
        return; 

        if(data.error === false){       
            $('#activities_list').html(data.msg).on('click', '.HistoricActivities', function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                recall(getURLParameter('page', this.href));

            });


        }


    }
).done( function(){

    $('.sub_note').shorten({
        moreText: 'read more',
        lessText: 'read less',
        showChars: '100'
    }); 
});

}



    $(function(){


        $('.HistoricActivities.dummy_his').click( function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            $('#activities_list').html('');

            recall(1);

        });

        $(window).on('load', function(){
            $('.dummy_his').click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's really the `.prefentDefault()` that doesn't work, you may just try to return `false`inside your eventhandler. That, too, should cancel the event.

Comment: This is false, if you look at the example you should see that it should perfectly work for the click handler: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @matteofigus As preventDefault is not part of jQery but of DOM, better take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault That site also states, that a) preventDefault doesn'T stop propagation, and b) that not all events are cancelable.

Comment: But it also says: "Calling preventDefault during any stage of event flow cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur."

Comment: @Calvin.Allen I was under the impressions that those events just are not cancelable. But because of your comments, I just tested it. Turned out you were right and I was wrong. So sorry for the trouble! Edited my post accordingly.